# What android device architectures should I build my app for?

Tags: android, arm, xamarin.android

Mono for Android gives me 3 options regarding the devices that my app should be built for:

- armeabi
- armeabi-v7a
- x86

What architecture(s) should I build my app for? And what exactly happens if I just build my app for armeabi?

Comment: Are you using the NDK? Or just, um, MonoDroid?

Comment: I'm using Monodroid, however Monodroid compiles .NET code into a regular APK file, so this question is in fact relevant to all android apps, not jus Monodroid.

Comment: "this question is in fact relevant to all android apps" -- the *question* may be, but the answer will not be. If MonoDroid uses the NDK to achieve its ends, the answer is very different than if MonoDroid does not.

Comment: IMO this question is really very specific to MonoDroid.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends which end devices you need to support.

The explanation on http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/architecture is:

> Native libraries containing the Mono runtime are present within the
>   .apk. A Mono for Android application must contain native libraries for
>   the desired/targeted Android architectures, e.g. armeabi, armeabi-v7a,
>   x86. Mono for Android applications cannot run on a platform unless it
>   contains the appropriate runtime libraries.

So, for example, if you want to tackle an x86 Android VM (or Google TV) then your apk will need to include the x86 native Mono libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So just to make sure I got this right - If I want to support all three architectures, I have no way of providing a download smaller than 8 MB?

Comment: I think I might have to defer that specific question to someone from Xamarin. However, as a user, I'm not sure why you'd need to include x86 for general distribution - you can always build separate apk's for x86 customers (whoever they are)